# Empty value field error when using for loop with embeds

Tags: discord.py

So i am trying to do something like this for my help menu:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Test(commands.Cog):
    """Fun commands"""
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed()
        for name, cog in self.client.cogs.items():
            cmds = cog.get_commands()
            cmdString = ''
            for command in cmds:
                cmdString += "```{}``` ".format(command.name)
                print(f'Cog Name: {name}, command: {command.name}')
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=cmdString)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Test(client))
````

But whenever i try to execute the command i get embed empty field error saying that value should not be empty.

Comment: Do all of your cogs have commands?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes every single cog has atleast 1 command.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: This works fine for me.  Are you loading any other cogs?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes i am, there are 4 other than this one. i guess if this works fine for you, i will go ahead and look more in to the code. I did print out the whole list of commands together with cog and did not get a single empty one though.

Comment: Update: Apparently one of the cog's command was not correctly registered (i forgot the decorator) and it didnt show up in the print i did in this code. fixed it.